# Why participants transact bitcoins use pseudonyms rather than persistent real-world identitie?

Tags: blockchain, privacy

I recently read an [article](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/03_meiklejohn-online.pdf) that tries to make reveal the identity of participants which transact bitcoins. my question is why participants use pseudonym instead of real-world identities and cause transaction be anonymous.
what is the use of this anonymity and why is blockchain structure designed in this form? wasn't it more safe if the identity of participants was clear?

Comment: have you read the bitcoin whitepaper?

Comment: yes, I have read some, but couldn't find an answer to my question @renlord

Answer (score 2):

Data privacy is one of the key designs of Blockchain technology.

If you expose the identity of the participants you expose all the transactions to the non-participants in those transacations which can make the entire system useless by way of generating all the data privacy issues such as Information mishandling, snooping and location tracking.